# Apache 2.4 / php-fpm 7.1 on OSX Mac. php-fpm ignores all requests, logs nothing

Tags: php, macos, apache

php-fpm 7.1 seems to have a very poorly written version for OSX because I am getting problems that I never seen on Linux or on Windows.

First of all it does not have any logging. If it fails to start it does not report any errors. I have error log path set but it does not use it.

Secondly even if it starts and I can see the working threads then it still does solid nothing. It does not respond to apache requests and logs nothing into access_logs

```
php-fpm   70353 stan    7u  IPv4 0x86d5d0a23f80531f      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9000 (LISTEN)
```

Httpd config is below

```
<Proxy "fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/" timeout=300>
</Proxy>

<FilesMatch \.php$>
SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1/:9000"
</FilesMatch>
```

php-fpm config

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
php_flag[display_errors] = on
php_admin_value[error_log] = /www-logs/fpm-php.www.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

Anyone had any luck making it works ?

Answer (score 0):

Find ANOTHER configuration file where path to log defined another time. And this another config file apparently took precedence over www.conf that is inside php-fpm.d folder

```
/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php-fpm.conf
```

This file has property

```
error_log
```

As for socket that I changed to unix socket. Was not able to figure out why it does not listen to port 9000. Nothing in the logs for that. So the bellow solution works

```
<IfDefine USE_PHP_FPM>
  <Proxy "unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock|fcgi://www-fpm" timeout=300>
  </Proxy>
  <FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://www-fpm/"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfDefine>
```

And php-fpm.d/www.conf

```
;listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
listen=/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock
```